# How to configure Shrew soft vpn client with SonicWall vpn server

Tags: vpn

our office has a SonicWall vpn server. I used to connect with it using SonicWall vpn client on Windows 7. It used to work great.

Recently, I have upgraded my OS to Windows 8. I tried to install SonicWall vpn client but that crashes my Windows 8 during installation. So after several installation failures, I decided to go with Shrew Soft VPN client which works great with our Client's Cisco vpn server.

But I'm not sure how to configure Shrew Soft VPN client with SonicWall VPN server.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. If you are not required to use the Cisco client, free ShrewSoft client is a good alternative as it works fine with Cisco VPN gateways.
Installation is very easy, and the configuration is even easier.  Just copy the .pcf file from a PC with Cisco VPN installed and configured, then import it into Shrewsoft VPN Client by clicking File–>Import and then selecting your Cisco VPN .pcf configuration file.

The following instruction could help either: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXutjGwCo00